# Running a gradle task multiple times with different parameters

Tags: javascript, gradle, minify

I am trying to write a gradle task which will minify all my project's javascript files. I am using a gradle library: `com.eriwen.gradle.js`. This library contains a task called `minifyJs` where we define the source file we want to minify and the destination of the minified file:

```
minifyJs {
  source = file(sourcePathString)
  dest = file(targetPathString)
}
```

What I want to do is call execute this task for EVERY javascript file in my project and produce a minified version of it in a new path for EACH file. This would require me to run the `minifyJs` task multiple times each time with different `source` and `dest` values, but I can't seem to find a solution on how to do this. One person had suggested that we use a loop to create a new task of `type: minifyJs` for each javascript file but this takes a huge amount of time and will create 250+ tasks i.e. not effective at all.

Since calling a task inside another task doesn't work (and using `task.execute()` is bad practice) I'm essentially looking for a workaround that lets me achieve this:

```
task customMinify {
  def jsFileTree = fileTree('my/javascript/files')
  jsFileTree.forEach {
    def jsFile = it
    minifyJs {
      source = file(jsFile.getPath())
      dest = file('new/path/to/file.js')
    }
  }
}
```

which obviously doesn't work since we can't call `minifyJs` inside another task.

Comment: Actually `source` accepts a list of sources. But there still will be single output for all the files. Does it help you somehow?

Comment: If it does not, you need to define an aggregate task and create as many tasks as many files you have. All these tasks will be run from aggregator.

Comment: Can you post an example? I know how to create new tasks using `tasks.create(name: 'taskName', type: 'taskType') {}` but after that I have no idea how to make the main task (or aggregator) execute them...

Comment: Note, I don't want gradle to create the tasks during the build phase. I want it to create them during the main task's execution. Otherwise i'll have over 200 tasks defined...

Comment: [Here](https://github.com/Opalo/stackoverflow/tree/master/34181468) is a demo I've prepared.

Comment: I did the same but it went ahead and created all the tasks before hand, on gradle build time. Then when I executed the aggregate task it executed correctly but now I have 250 tasks on my task list in intellij. Is there a way to avoid this? Essentially I want gradle to dynamically create the tasks when I call the aggregate task, execute them then destroy them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm really sorry that this gap has continued to exist in the *gradle-js-plugin*.

Since generating tasks won't do, I suggest that you [write a custom task](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/custom_tasks.html) under `buildSrc` combining my [JsMinifier](https://github.com/eriwen/gradle-js-plugin/blob/master/src/main/groovy/com/eriwen/gradle/js/JsMinifier.groovy) and the [MinifyJsTask](https://github.com/eriwen/gradle-js-plugin/blob/master/src/main/groovy/com/eriwen/gradle/js/tasks/MinifyJsTask.groovy).

If you're willing to wait 8 hours or so, I can write an implementation of this later if you like.

EDIT: Here's a [gist for a ClosureMinifyTask](https://gist.github.com/eriwen/bc9933b1c93b42dfd541) you can throw in `buildSrc/src/main/groovy/com/eriwen/gradle/js/tasks` and it'll minify each file individually and produce individual source map files etc.

buildSrc/build.gradle:

```
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    compile localGroovy()
    compile gradleApi()
    compile ('com.google.javascript:closure-compiler:v20151015') {
        exclude module: 'junit'
    }
}
```

Sample Usage:

```
task mini(type: com.foo.bar.ClosureMinifyTask) {
    source = "src/js"
    dest = "${buildDir}/js/minified"
}
```

Comment: Wow didn't expect a same day fix from the creator himself. Although I'm a little confused on how to implement the `ClosureMinifyTask`. Right now I'm using your library as a plugin. I'm guessing I'll have to clone the project in my desktop and use it from there? Also if you implement the new functionality at some point in a newer version, what is essentially needed is a way to give a set of file paths and have the minifier 'clone' a minified version of each file in a totally new location with a totally new name (so as to not have each minified file mixed up with the source ones).

Comment: I tried downloading the whole project from github and adding the class but I can't seem to be able to compile it into a new .jar once again. For some reason IntelliJ isn't able to read the libraries in the classpath and I can't be sure it isn't some configuration from the `build.gradle` file that's causing the problem.

Comment: Also if it would be possible to give an example on how to use `compilerOptions` because I can't seem to be able to get it to work. I wrote: `closure { compilerOptions = coObject }` where `coObject = new CompilerOptions()` and `coObject.setLanguageIn(CompilerOptions.LanguageMode.ECMASCRIPT5` but it still fails to minify scripts with trailing commas...

Comment: @Konstantine: You don't need to modify the plugin at all, but I did leave out the build.gradle part of buildSrc - I'll add that to my answer.

Comment: @Konstantine The gradle-js-plugin itself uses an old version of the Closure Compiler that may not have ECMASCRIPT5 option; however, what I've provided here is the latest and should work. The only thing to watch out for is that this Task does not utilize the custom js sourceSets so you have to specify a directory.

Comment: The `.groovy` class you provided solved the problem. Also I learned a bit more about how gradle works and how to use `buildSrc` which I had no idea what it actually was until now...

Comment: I'm at a loss on how to use `compilerOptions` with the implementation you have provided. I admit I'm starting to learn groovy and haven't grasped exactly how everything works. I tried adding `closure {compilerOptions = cOpts}` under the `dest` declaraction but compiler fails. I also tried `closure = {...}` still fail...

Comment: @Konstantine shoot. Yeah, you'll have to copy the `ClosureCompilerExtension` into your buildSrc from the gradle-js-plugin project here: https://github.com/eriwen/gradle-js-plugin/blob/master/src/main/groovy/com/eriwen/gradle/js/ClosureCompilerExtension.groovy to get the compilerOptions working. Sorry, I spaced that out.

Comment: Ugh I'm disappointed at myself but I still can't get it to work. Without the `ClosureCompilerExtension` now I'm getting this error message: `Could not find property 'closure' on root project 'MyProject'.` I tried adding `closure` inside the minify task, I tried adding it inside the project's `ext { }`, the message changes but it still doesn't work. I checked the code and at some point it is looking for: `project.closure.externs` and I'm guessing that's what is causing the problem. It either can't find `closure` or the `externs` inside closure.

Comment: Nah, it's not your fault at all. I didn't fully consider the closure options before giving you my solutions. I'm going to write you a full solution this evening.